# How to execute conditionals after target-specific variables have been set?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that uses both pattern-specific variables and target-specific variables to control compile settings.  Individual targets can specify target-specific variables to override more general compile settings.  Some settings are mutually exclusive, however, and I'm stymied by how to add conditionals to the makefile to adjust a setting based on another one *after* target-specific variables have been set for a recipe.

My makefile runs on an IBM i (GNU Make 4.0), which many people are unfamiliar with, so here is a fabricated example that hopefully will make more sense to most:

```
.PHONY: all
all: object1.o object2.o

%.o: TYPE = solid
%.o: ITEM = stone

%.o: %.c
    compile_command -type $(TYPE) -item $(ITEM)

object1.o: ITEM = helium
object1.o: object1.c

object2.o: ITEM = water
object2.o: object2.c
```

The pattern-specific variables set up default values for `TYPE` and `ITEM` for all `.o` files.  `object1.o` overrides `ITEM` to "helium".  How can a conditional be inserted so that if `ITEM` equals "helium" then `TYPE` can automatically be set to "gas"?  Similarly, if `ITEM` equals "water" then how do we automatically set `TYPE` to "liquid"?  The goal is to avoid having to explicitly specify `TYPE` as a target-specific variable; it should be able to be derived by the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
GASSES = helium argon
LIQUIDS = water
derive_type = $(or $(if $(filter $(ITEM),$(GASSES)),gas),$(if $(filter $(ITEM),$(LIQUIDS)),liquid),$(TYPE))

%.o: %.c
        compile_command -type $(derive_type) -item $(ITEM)
```

Basically, the `or` function is short-circuiting and returns the first item in the passed-in list that is non-empty, and the `filter` function returns a matching value.  So this says, return the first value which is "gas" if the value of `ITEM` exists in the `$(GASSES)` variable, ditto for `$(LIQUIDS)` and `liquid`, and if all else fails return the value of the `$(TYPE)` value.

There may be some work to do related to the default value, if you want to allow `TYPE` to be the first one chosen if set.

Comment: So it sounds like at the time my variable needs to be used in the recipe, that's when you'd do this process -- because by then all the target-specific variables have already been set.  Is it possible to set the value of other variables from within a conditional?  I get that you can say `x = $(some_expression_that_calculates_x)`, but is there a way to stick a conditional in that that basically says `if x = 'some_value' then set y to 3 and z to 4`?

Comment: You can do it, with `eval`, but it's not easy to use.  It also might not be the best way to do things: you might consider using computed variable names for that, for example.  That doesn't sound like the same question you were asking above and the answer is too complex for a comment.  I recommend you start a different SO question that asks for the real info you want, if this question isn't actually reflective of that.